# Authentication flow in react-native problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react-native navigation. I currently have two Stacks `AuthenicationStack` where I have the login and signup screen. The second Stack `MainStack` where I have the main screens which appears after the users login.

in App.js I check the token to see if the user is already logged in and here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthenticationStack from './src/navigation/AuthenticationStack';
import MainStack from './src/navigation/MainStack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'


export default function App() {

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')
    .then((value) => {
      console.log('userId: ', value);
      setUserId(value);
    })
  AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    .then((value) => {
      console.log('token: ',value);
      setToken(value);
    })

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        {
          token ?
            <MainStack />
          :
            <AuthenticationStack />
        }
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
```

and here is my AuthenticationStack:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';


import Login from '../components/Login/Login';
import Signup from '../components/Signup/Signup';

const AuthenticationStack = () => {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="login">
            <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={Signup} />
            
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default AuthenticationStack;
```

MainStack:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';


import Home from '../components/Home/Home';

const MainStack = () => {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
            <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
            {/* I want to add more screens here */}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default MainStack;
```

So, when the user launches the app the app do what is supposed to do and check which stack to render. My Question is when I login in `Login.js` how to go to the `MainStack` and when I logout from the `Home.js` in the `MainStack` how do I go to the `AuthenticationStack` ?